# How can i return a null in linq?

Tags: c#

I have an expression in linq

```
  var ismatch = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(type));
  if (ismatch != null)
  {
    //....
  }
  else 
  {
   //....
  }
```

The problem is that it gives an exception:

```
 value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"
```

type is null. I want to be able to return a nulll if it cant find the value in the list.
How can i do this ?

Comment: What is type of your `list` and `type`?

Comment: if the `Contains` method of the items in the list, does not allow `null`-values as arguments, then you need to check before you call with `x => type != null && x.Contains(type)`. I am assuming that type is a plain reference type, not a nullable value type.

Comment: issue is that type is not in the list .. so i need to check that type is not not null and then check if it is in the list.

Comment: Both `List<T>.Contains(T value)` and `Enumerable.Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,  T value)` accept `null` as input to search for. So the error is somewhere else.
For example here: `x => x.Contains(type)` will throw a nullref when `list` contains `null`'s.
`x => x?.Contains(type) == true` could fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code `list` seems a list of lists or at least a list of enumerables, likely of `Type`.
In case the enumerables in list, themselves contain nulls, you'll get a NullReferenceException in the evaluation of your FirstOrDefault-lambda, where you rely on each element being not null. Which you can fix by:

```
  var match = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x?.Contains(type) == true);
  if (match != null)
  {
    //....
  }
  else 
  {
   //....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that it is not null before Use with Contains

```
if (type == null)
{
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
}
    
var ismatch = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(type));
if (ismatch.Any())
{
//....
}
else 
{
//....
}
```

Comment: The name of the list is `list` not `ismatch`. `ismatch` should be the first item in the list, which itself is some sort of collection, containing the element `type`.

Comment: You put the result of the list in ismatch, So we check ismatch in condition

Comment: The code of the OP does not reach the `if` statement because of the exception, at least that is how I understand his question.

Comment: no it doesnt reach the if statement... sorry but im a her not a his !